# The key is here

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, steganography

My intuition may not be clear

But here is the key to what I hold dear

An equation between the lines

Which ties you to I

Comment: How about a hint?

Comment: Yes please. A hint would help

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it might have something to do with

> The QWERTY keyboard, where 'U' (you) and I are next to each other. The keys above and below these two keys (the 'key' to what I hold dear, an equation between the lines), may be:
>
>  J = 8

Comment: it does have to do with the keyboard but if you. "see what you need" you should be able to get an other poem